# sh -c not get the right output when execute shell script

Tags: shell

I loop to get data from array in shell ,
It works when I execute it in a shell file, with this content:

```
arr=(1 2 3 4 5)  
for var in ${arr[@]};  
do  
    echo $var  
done
```

But there isn't any output when I use `sh -c` like below:

```
sh -c "arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in ${arr[@]};do echo $var;done"
```

Comment: Note that `printf` will iterate if you provide more values than placeholders. Your `for` loop can be written like this: `bash -c 'arr=(1 2 3 4 5); printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"'`

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is using `sh -c "..."`, see [@Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228950/38906) for more details.

Further more, `sh` (refer to [POSIX sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html)) does not support array (strictly speaking, it has only one array, [$@](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02)), you need to call other shells on your system, which support array like `bash`, `zsh` or `ksh`.

```
bash -c 'arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in "${arr[@]}";do echo "$var"; done'
```

Also note that you have a mistake when leaving `${arr[@]}` un-quote, actually you need `for var in "${arr[@]}"` instead. [Invoking variable without quotes calling split+glob and is source of many security implication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906).

To play with POSIX sh, you can use [$@](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137571/38906):

```
set -- 1 2 3 4 5
for var do
  printf '%s\n' "$var"
done
```

Comment: I'd also recommend to attach shebang https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29 at the beggining of EACH script.

Comment: @MateuszPacek: The OP calling `sh -c` inline script instead of creating a shell script. the shebang didn't help in this case.

Comment: @ccuonglm yes, that's true. But when you got script in file it's easier to exec it inline if you know what kind of shell implementation you used to use.

Comment: this works with single quote sh -c 'arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in ${arr[@]};do echo $var;done'

Comment: @c4f4t0r this works only if your `sh` isn't really `sh` but is actually `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh` in poor disguise. You shouldn't really use `bash` features with the shell invoked as `sh` as one day it may break (consider Debian with `sh` a symlink to `dash` rather than `bash`).

Comment: yes, I'm using centos and sh is symlink to bash

Comment: @c4f4t0r, still, avoid bad practices: use the most precise interpreter for your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you used the wrong type of quotes. Shells interpolate variables inside double quotes, so the variable references were interpolated by the shell in which you ran `sh -c "…"`. Assuming that this shell didn't have variables named `arr` or `var` defined, the argument to `sh -c` was

```
arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in ;do echo ;done
```

If `sh` is a shell that supports arrays, this is perfectly valid code, that happens to do nothing.

To pass a literal string to a command, use single quotes. All characters inside single quotes are interpreted literally, so you can use every character except a single quote in the string. (If you need a single quote, [escape it as the four-character sequence `'\''`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69144/how-do-i-escape-a-sub-directory-name-with-an-ampersand-in-it/69147#69147).)

```
sh -c 'arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in ${arr[@]};do echo $var;done'
```

Beware that not all implementations of `sh` support arrays. If you need arrays, you should explicitly invoke a shell that supports them.

```
ksh -c 'arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in ${arr[@]};do echo $var;done'
```

or

```
bash -c 'arr=(1 2 3 4 5);for var in ${arr[@]};do echo $var;done'
```